# Can't access enum within struct

Tags: c, struct, enums

I have the following struct defined

Header File:

```
struct SDK {
   enum {
       HEADER0 = 0,
       HEADER1,
       LINGO,
       COMMAND,
       LENGTH,
       ACK_CMD,
       ACK_STATUS
   }commandFormat;
}mySDK;
```

and I want to use it like this:

main.c

```
switch (rxData[mySDK.commandFormat.LINGO]) {
   default:
      break;
}
```

I am getting the error: request for member 'LINGO' in something not a structure or union

I know I'm probably doing something stupid, but I can't figure out what exactly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct SDK {
   enum {
       HEADER0 = 0,
       HEADER1,
       LINGO,
       COMMAND,
       LENGTH,
       ACK_CMD,
       ACK_STATUS
   }commandFormat;
}mySDK;
```

creates integer constants

```
   HEADER0,
   HEADER1,
   LINGO,
   COMMAND,
   LENGTH,
   ACK_CMD,
   ACK_STATUS
```

in the **global** scope.

It also defines

```
struct SDK {
   enum <anonymous> commandFormat;
};
```

where the debugger will interpret the values of `commandFormat` as one the above integer constants,
and it defines an instance of that struct named `mySDK`.

`mySDK.commandFormat` is an integer (enum).
It doesn't make sense to apply `.` to it.

Comment: can tell difference if we create enum inside struct vs class?

Comment: @MuhammadRezaIrvanda There's no difference, AFAIK. I think only C++ nests enums. In plain C, they always go to file scope.

Comment: @MuhammadRezaIrvanda Yup, I tested it. In C, the constants leak to the file scope, whereas in C++ they/'re accessible with `SDK::HEADER0`, etc. or from within SDK member functions, if it has any.

Comment: Ok, so is there a way that I can use an enum value as an index in an array?

Comment: @IanOswald Any integer type is usable in indexing. An` enum` will be an integer type (with a range smaller or equal to that of `int`).

Comment: I understand that, how should I change my code in order to make that work?

Comment: That doesn't give me what I need though as commandFormat doesn't have a value associated with it. I want to use the LINGO as the index in the array.

Comment: `switch (rxData[LINGO]) {`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139617/discussion-between-ian-oswald-and-pskocik).

Answer (score 0):

Just write

```
switch (rxData[mySDK.commandFormat]) {
```

provided that the data member `commandFormat` of the object `mySDK` was initialized in particularly with `LINGO`.

Or write

```
switch (rxData[INGO]) {
```

Comment: I want to access the index pointed to by a specific member of commandFormat without having to nest an if/else.

Comment: That won't work either as it isn't a member of the struct and shows as "unable to resolve identifier."

Comment: @IanOswald It seems you are compiling the program as a C++ program. In C this code is valid.

Comment: @IanOswald Or you have two enumerations with the same enumerator.